# Gradle Kotlin DSL Files - Separate Config Files

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm currently in the process of migrating my groovy gradle files to kotlin.  I have jacoco and sonarcloud integrated into my application.  I have separate groovy gradle files for jacoco and sonar config and apply them to my `build.gradle(:app)` as follows:

```
apply from: '../jacoco/modules.gradle'
apply from: 'sonar.gradle'
```

The top of my sonar.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
    properties {
```

I have tried converting this file to kotlin

e.g. `apply(plugin = "org.sonarqube")` but I get the error that sonarqube cannot be found.  Is this possible to have configurations extracted to separate gradle kotlin dsl files the way it could be done with Groovy?  If so, could someone shed some light on what to do next?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
I have added in the `buildSrc` folder structure which looks like this:

[image]
and the contents of my `build.gradle.kts` as follows:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.4.1.3373"
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And the contents of my `sonar.gradle.kts` is as follows:

```
apply(plugin = "org.sonarqube")

sonarqube {
    
}
```

I know I have done something wrong here but I don't know what as `sonarqube` throws up an error.

If I reference `sonarqube` in `build.gradle.kts` it is picked up.

However I don't want that structure and if I try to add `id("org.sonarqube") version "4.4.1.3373"` into the `sonar.gradle.kts` file it give the following error:

```
Invalid plugin request [id: 'org.sonarqube', version: '4.4.1.3373']. 

Plugin requests from precompiled scripts must not include a version number. 
Please remove the version from the offending request and make sure the 
module containing the requested plugin 'org.sonarqube' is 
an implementation dependency of project ':buildSrc'.
```

Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this now is to use a "[precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins)".

This is a standalone `.gradle.kts` file that you can include like a plugin in one of your regular `build.gradle.kts` files.

This needs to be located in an [included build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_builds), and the easiest way to set up an included build is to use the [buildSrc folder](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources), which is a default included build.

To get this to work:

1. Set up a `buildSrc` folder and place a `build.gradle.kts` file as follows:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This file should declare as dependencies any artifacts you need for your script plugin, including any JARs for external plugins ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#applying_external_plugins_in_precompiled_script_plugins)), just as if you were including them for a regular Kotlin JVM application. (This also places them on the classpath of your whole build.)

2. Write your script plugin in a file named `my-first-kotlin-script-plugin.gradle.kts` in the `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` folder:

```
plugins {
    // some useful plugins
}

tasks {
    // some fabulous tasks
}
```

3. Then you can include your new script plugin in regular `build.gradle.kts` files:

```
plugins {
    `my-first-kotlin-script-plugin`
}

// use useful plugins and fabulous tasks
```

Comment: That's great information, thank you.  So to confirm the `build.gradle.kts` in my `buildSrc` structure is separate from both the project `build.gradle.kts` and the app `build.gradle.kts` ?

Comment: If I've understood you correctly: yes, you need a brand new, separate `build.gradle.kts` file inside your `buildSrc` folder to make this work. It's another Gradle project

Comment: Thank you Simon, so I've aded that structure and added the sonar plugin to the `build.gradle.kts` as follows:

`plugins {
    kotlin-dsl
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.4.1.3373"
}`

However in my `sonar.gradle.kts` it is still not picking up sonarqube

Comment: I have updated my original post to illustrate my issue

Comment: You need to put the JAR for the plugin on the script plugin classpath using `dependencies { implementation("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:4.4.1.3373") }` in the new `build.gradle.kts` file and remove references to that plugin's version elsewhere. This is the point I talk about at the end of point 1 in my answer

Comment: add `gradlePluginPortal()` to your repositories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256820/discussion-between-simon-jacobs-and-dj-doo).

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin DSL, you should have something like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
  id("org.sonarqube")
}
```