How to properly use extension gradle.kts in your module?
This is my extension .kts with name
android-library-build.gradle.kts
Here with error:
e: file:///.../myapp/android-library-build.gradle.kts:2:11: Unresolved reference: libs

(libs.~) get id from .toml
or android-library-build.kts
with error:
Caused by: org.gradle.groovy.scripts.ScriptCompilationException: Could not compile script '/.../myapp/android-library-build.kts'.


plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.app.core"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 23

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

}

My usage in core module
apply {
    from("$rootDir/android-library-build.gradle.kts")
}

dependencies {
[...]
}

If I directly write it in my core gradle module it works, but if I want to apply it doesn't work.
How to fix it?

Try following the instructions in this answer and see how you get on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77954295/gradle-kotlin-dsl-files-separate-config-files/77954564#77954564
